# Rancher continuously restarts MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, rancher

After upgrade to rancher 1.3 from 1.1 we have problem in running mongodb cluster.
Suddenly rancher without reasons keeps restarting at least one node of the mogodb cluster claiming that it's incomplete.
Below you can find a fragment of rancher log (look at the end first as a reversed order log):

```
01:19:17 PM INFO    service.trigger.info    Requested: 3, Created: 3, Unhealthy: 0, Bad: 0, Incomplete: 0    
01:19:17 PM INFO    service.trigger.info    Service already reconciled   
01:19:16 PM INFO    service.trigger Re-evaluating state  
01:19:16 PM INFO    service.trigger (1 sec) Re-evaluating state  
01:19:16 PM INFO    service.trigger.info    Service reconciled: Requested: 3, Created: 3, Unhealthy: 0, Bad: 0, Incomplete: 0    
01:19:16 PM INFO    service.update.info Service already reconciled   
01:19:16 PM INFO    service.update  Updating service     
01:19:16 PM INFO    service.update.info Requested: 3, Created: 3, Unhealthy: 0, Bad: 0, Incomplete: 0    
01:19:16 PM INFO    service.trigger.exception   Busy processing [SERVICE.280] will try later     
01:19:03 PM INFO    service.update  Updating service     
01:19:03 PM INFO    service.update.exception    Busy processing [SERVICE.280] will try later     
01:19:02 PM INFO    service.trigger.wait (14 sec)   Waiting for instances to start   
01:19:02 PM INFO    service.instance.create Creating extra service instance  
01:19:02 PM INFO    service.instance.create Creating extra service instance  
01:19:01 PM INFO    service.trigger (15 sec)    Re-evaluating state  
01:19:01 PM INFO    service.trigger.info    Requested: 3, Created: 3, Unhealthy: 0, Bad: 0, Incomplete: 1
```

the problem always starts with `Requested: 3, Created: 3, Unhealthy: 0, Bad: 0, Incomplete:1`

However in the very same time in the mongo nothing interesting is happening, suddenly it's being restarted by something external i.e. rancher (log in natural order):

```
2017-01-22T13:06:11.957+0000 I NETWORK  [conn2362] end connection 10.42.191.72:55615 (24 connections now open)
2017-01-22T13:06:14.848+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.42.191.72:55635 #2363 (25 connections now open)
2017-01-22T13:06:14.849+0000 I NETWORK  [conn2363] end connection 10.42.191.72:55635 (24 connections now open)
(nothing unusual until here, look here)->
2017-01-22T13:06:15.243+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2017-01-22T13:06:15.244+0000 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2017-01-22T13:06:15.253+0000 I REPL     [signalProcessingThread] Stopping replication applier threads
2017-01-22T13:06:15.556+0000 I STORAGE  [conn105] got request after shutdown()
2017-01-22T13:06:15.871+0000 I STORAGE  [conn91] got request after shutdown()
2017-01-22T13:06:15.874+0000 I STORAGE  [conn86] got request after shutdown()
2017-01-22T13:06:15.887+0000 I STORAGE  [conn82] got request after shutdown()
2017-01-22T13:06:15.941+0000 I STORAGE  [conn83] got request after shutdown()
2017-01-22T13:06:16.009+0000 I STORAGE  [conn85] got request after shutdown()
2017-01-22T13:06:16.020+0000 I STORAGE  [conn84] got request after shutdown()
2017-01-22T13:06:16.108+0000 I STORAGE  [conn75] got request after shutdown()
2017-01-22T13:06:16.133+0000 I STORAGE  [conn87] got request after shutdown()
```

Any idea what could be worng with rancher. I even try and created clean mongodb having no clients same story is being restarted by rancher at lease twice an hour sometimes more often. 
Any workaround?